# Camel JMS SQS long polling

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, amazon-sqs

Currently using camel JMS and have it listening to a queue in SQS.
I'm trying to reduce the amount of empty receives. Currently have 3 per minute and would like to reduce to 1.

My bean code looks like:

```
@Bean(name = "jms")
@ConditionalOnClass(JmsComponent.class)
public JmsComponent jmsComponent(SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory) {
    JmsComponent jmsComponent = new JmsComponent();
    jmsComponent.setConnectionFactory(sqsConnectionFactory);
    return jmsComponent;
}
```

I have tried the following:

- set receive message wait time to 20 secs in the queue
- setRequestTimeout of the jmsComponent to 60 secs
- setReceiveTimeout of the jmsComponent to 60 secs

After doing the above I can still see 3 empty reads per minute.

Answer (score -1):

There is a 20sec wait time limit on the side of SQS, so this is probably not possible.

> When the wait time for the ReceiveMessage API action is greater than 0, long polling is in effect. The maximum long polling wait time is 20 seconds.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/working-with-messages.html#setting-up-long-polling